# Why is [[ ! ! expr ]] equivalent to [[ ! expr ]] in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

In bash, I don't understand why the 3rd command isn't true:

```sh
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]]         # $? is 0
[[ ! 1 -eq 1 ]]       # $? is 1
[[ ! ! 1 -eq 1 ]]     # $? is 1 (??)
[[ ! ( ! 1 -eq 1 ) ]] # $? is 0
```

It seems to do the same thing if I replace `1 -eq 1` with any true expression, and negate with any false expression.

Comment: FWIW, `[[ ! ! 1 == 1 ]]; echo $?` works as expected in `zsh`.

Comment: "expected" -- the POSIX `test` standard doesn't set that expectation.

Comment: My expectation would be: `syntax error`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...and, of course, a syntax error will always have a non-success exit status, so that's consistent with the `1` that the OP reports. (It also complies with POSIX guidance for `[`, as a syntax error is a member of the infinite set of things one can legitimately do when presented with input for which behavior is unspecified).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it doesn't seem to be a syntax error because `[[ ! ! 0 -eq 1 ]]` has an exit code of 0.

Comment: @vimene, ...one of the beautiful things about "results are unspecified" is that _anything_ is allowed. As folks over in the C tag have been known to say, given input that invokes unspecified behavior, the compiler could emit code that eats your cat; anything is permitted.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `[[`, and I strongly prefer `[` since its warts are well known.  If `[[` is indeed treating `! ! 1 -eq 1` as 5 arguments instead of treating `! 1 -eq 1` as a single expression and evaluating the first `!` as a negation of that expression, I think this firmly plants the nail in the coffin for it as a usable construct.  (In my mind, that final nail was planted years ago!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...I don't particularly agree as to the judgment you're making -- `test` is subject to undefined behavior and ambiguous corners in the specification itself -- hence the XSI extensions being marked obsolescent to reduce the room for surprising behavior. Stick to the non-obsolescent parts of `test`, and the parts of `[[` that either map to those non-obsolescent bits or are themselves explicitly well-documented (`=~`, `=` with globs on the right-hand side, etc) and you've got comparable levels of predictability either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing `!`, bash sets a flag to the following expression to tell it to invert its result. Because of this, parsing two or more `!` is equivalent to parsing a single `!`. I proposed a [patch](https://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?10070) to fix this, and it got accepted.

Answer (score 8):

`[[` is an extended syntax that provides (mostly) a superset of `[`. To understand its behavior, then, one should start from the standard for `[`.

[The POSIX `test` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) describes how `[` is expected to behave. In one place, it does provide a description in line with the expectations described in this question:

> `! expression` - True if expression is false. False if expression is true.

...but later on, the more detailed description of how parsing occurs based on number of primitives contradicts this expectation:

> - 0 arguments: Exit false (1).
> - 1 argument: Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.
> - 2 arguments: **If $1 is `!`, exit true if $2 is null, false if $2 is not null.**
>   If $1 is a unary primary, exit true if the unary test is true, false if the unary test is false.
>   Otherwise, produce unspecified results.
> - 3 arguments: If $2 is a binary primary, perform the binary test of $1 and $3.
>   **If $1 is '!', negate the two-argument test of $2 and $3.**
>   (Obsolescent XSI behavior: If $1 is '(' and $3 is ')', perform the unary test of $2..
>   On systems that do not support the XSI option, the results are unspecified if $1 is '(' and $3 is ')'.
>   Otherwise, produce unspecified results.
> - 4 arguments: **If $1 is '!', negate the three-argument test of $2, $3, and $4.**
>   (Obsolescent XSI behavior: If $1 is '(' and $4 is ')', perform the two-argument test of $2 and $3.)
>   On systems that do not support the XSI option, the results are unspecified if $1 is '(' and $4 is ')'.
>   Otherwise, the results are unspecified.
> - More than 4 arguments: **The results are unspecified.**

In the case of `! ! 1 -eq 1`, you have a five-argument case. **The results are unspecified**, as the standard does not specify that a five-argument case is the negation of a four-argument case if the first argument is `!`.

---

As suggested by Zilog80: If you don't want to be subject to these restrictions, consider putting your `!` *outside* the test syntax; `! [[ ... ]]` happens at a the shell command parsing layer instead of in bespoke test-syntax-specific logic, and `! ! [[ ... ]]` is perfectly valid there.

Comment: AFAIK, a correct way to negate is `! ! [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]` ,  if that worth be mentioned.

Comment: @Zilog80, I agree; that approach is subject to the POSIX sh standard instead of the POSIX test standard, and double negations are valid there.

Comment: Not really. The standard documents `[`, not `[[`, so, even `[[ string ]]` is unspecified.

Comment: @oguzismail, ...granted, it's not strictly POSIX-specified, but it's an extension of the standard, so the standard gives it something to aim towards (subject to documented places where it diverges). That's closer to having a canonical reference than otherwise.

Comment: Nah, I'm not convinced. `[ ! ! 1 -eq 1 ]` works fine, Bash clearly implements double negation and 3+ arguments in the test builtin. The problem is with `[[`, try `set -x; [[ ! ! 1-eq 1 ]]` and you'll see that `! !` (or any number of consequent bangs) are truncated to `!`. And if you look at the source code (parse.y specifically, reallh hard to read), there's nothing that reverses the effect of `!` when it is followed by another `!`.

Comment: @oguzismail, ...I wonder if we're talking past each other. The point I'm making is only that the behavior is unspecified, which means the shell is _under no obligation_ to make that flag a toggle vs something that gets set and stays set; it's just as correct for it to keep its current implementation as it would be to have a toggle-based one that behaves the way the OP expects. (Of course, being unspecified also means it could switch to doing it the other way in a new release without breaking any guarantees... but then, it could also switch back).

Comment: I find it odd that `bash` collapses any chain of `!`s to a single `!`; I don't know of any sensible interpretation of the operator that should be idempotent.

Comment: According to the [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html), "the expression is parsed and evaluated according to precedence". But I'm not sure if `[[` follows these rules.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But the `[[ ]]` conditional expression doesn't follow the same syntax as `test`, and its entire point is to fix various problems with `test` syntax (like possibly ambiguities in how longer/omre complex expressions are parsed).

Comment: @vimene, not all of the precedence discussion in the docs for `test` applies since `-a` and `-o` don't exist in `[[`. It's noteworthy that the upstream-test extensions are flagged as obsolescent in large part because they lead to ambiguities. Those ambiguities don't matter to `[[`, though, since its use of `&&`, `||`, and indeed `(` and `)` as well can distinguish syntax from data (`[` can't tell the difference between a `!` resulting from a variable expansion and one written in the code, but `[[` absolutely can).

Comment: @vimene, ...all that said, you may well have a behavior here that Chet would consider a bug. Emailing the bug-bash@gnu.org mailing list is not necessarily a bad idea. (I still would consider it a bad idea to write code that depends on this behavior, since any fix wouldn't be portable back to earlier shell releases).